# Image is not refreshing automatically after saving changes in Photoshop

Tags: windows, photoshop

Usually when I edited and saved changes in Photoshop - this image automatically updated while being open in Windows photo viewer.

Now I have a new laptop and after any changes in Photoshop image is not updating. I has to reopen it. I notice however that if I change the image in Paint ans save - it triggers updates in Windows photo viewer. Which is something that I want to happen in case with Photoshop, since it worked perfectly on other machine. Struggle to find a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for now I just switched to using FastStone as an image viewer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).